# The line was indented 2 levels deeper than the previous line. HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, view, haml

```
 =image_tag('/images/public_stream_page/overlay_image.png',
:onload=>"document.getElementById('dd_mid_right_box_public').style.background='url(#{stream.asset.url(:normal)})';")
```

This is my haml code to display an image
so am getting this error

```
The line was indented 2 levels deeper than the previous line.
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not displaying the code in a correct way for a problem that relates to space indentation...
Also line numbers would help.
You should have something like this:

```
- if stream.asset? 
  =image_tag('/images/public_stream_page/overlay_image.png',:onload=>"document.getElementById('dd_mid_right_box_public').style.background='url(#{stream.asset.url(:normal)})';")
```

With the second line indented with the same number of spacing you use in the rest of your templeate, while perhaps you have one line (number in the error not shown) 2 times more indented.

Comment: OOH was it related to space.? Today only I am started HAML.So you are saying space indentation is a matter in HAML and not in ERB ...right?

Comment: yeap in haml spaces matters, and beware of using tabs as well (unless you use just those), I can't have a day without seeing this error :(

Comment: @ecoologic :D Can do me one more favour.Upvote my question.so that i will get reputation to voteup answers..Now i can´t..

Comment: you'll get the missing point by accepting an answer on a question you have still open.

Comment: HAML is based on indentation, so it's crucial that they are either spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 6):

Probably not the direct answer to OP's question, but I ran into this error because the first few lines of my HAML were only indented by one space, and then it ran into a section of the document that was indented using two spaces. Apparently the HAML processor uses the first couple of lines to figure out how many spaces are in an indent, and then it enforces that throughout.